# ayuda con group by en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Tengo que sacar el monto total por cada unidad que tengo en mi tabla, el problema esta que un registro que supuestamente es de la unidad 3 pertenece a la unidad 1, no se como agrupar para que quede de manera correcta, esta es mi consulta.

```
select SUM(TOTAL) as total, SUBSTRING(UNIDAD,1,1) as unidad from estruc_programatica group by unidad;
```

solo puedo obtener lo de la tercer tabla, que muestro en la imagen pero quiero la tabla de en medio, el registro que tengo que agrupar  con la unidad 1 es el 3180, seria {1100,1200, 3180} la unidad 1, {2300} la unidad 2 y {3900, 3050} la unidad tres. Ya llevo rato intentando sacarlo, pero no puedo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba cambiando el nombre al alias de unidad, algo así select SUM(TOTAL) as total, SUBSTRING(UNIDAD,1,1) as unidadG from estruc_programatica group by unidadG;

Comment: da lo mismo, debe de haber una condición para poder agrupar una unidad que quiero con otra, pero no me da.

Comment: Karla, pareciera que lo que te falta, es agrupar correctamente, es decir agregar un `group by SUBSTRING(UNIDAD,1,1)` sin embargo, hay algo que no me cuadra en tu ejemplo, por que ninguno de los resultados se corresponde con las sumas de los registros iniciales.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si sale el resultado bien, es la tercer tabla me estan sumando cada monto perteneciente a la unidad 1, 2 y 3, la unidad la dice el primer dígito de mi tabla del campo unidad, pero mi duda es que la unidad 3180 en realidad no pertenece a la unidad 3, si no que es de la 1, es la única excepción por eso no se como podría agrupar el 3180 con el 1100 y 1200 y hace la suma de eso, como es la segunda tabla, obtengo lo de la tercer tabla.

Comment: ¿Cómo existen esos datos realmente en la tabla `estruc_programatica`?  Me parece que se podría llegar a una solución más fácil organizando mejor la tabla e incluyendo quizá otra tabla que maneje las relaciones. Lo que no veo en tu ejemplo es qué es lo que hace que `1100,1200, 3180` pertenezcan a la unidad 1, `2300` a la unidad 2 y `3900, 3050` a la unidad 3. ¿Hay algo que exprese esa relación en alguna parte? ¿dónde y cómo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que indicas, quieres agrupar por el primer caracter de `unidad` salvo la `unidad == 3180` que correspondería a la unidad `1`. Deberías hacer algo así:

```
select  SUM(TOTAL) as total, 
        CASE WHEN UNIDAD = 3180 THEN 1 ELSE SUBSTRING(UNIDAD,1,1) END as unidad 
        from estruc_programatica 
        group by CASE WHEN UNIDAD = 3180 THEN 1 ELSE SUBSTRING(UNIDAD,1,1) END;
```

Aclaración: Si no lo tienes, es recomendable contar con una tabla secundaria que haga la relación entre las unidades originales y la "unidad" que estas buscando, de esta forma podrías manejar mas elegantemente estas excepciones, por ejemplo: `(3180, 1)`

Comment: Gracias Patricio, creo que aun me falta aprender, funciones que se pueden hacer en mysql, no pensé que se pudiera trabajar con CASE en una consulta, solo en sp, gracias y tomare tu consejo.